# AWS sagemaker training job (Tensorflow) halts at Epoch 1

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to train Maskrcnn with custom dataset. The code is running fine on my local machine in the same docker container, however, it gets stuck at the first epoch when I use aws sagemaker.

[The log my error seen on sagemaker notebook for training job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3Z1T.png)

I am using Tensorflow 2 implementing the github code provided by https://github.com/simone-viozzi/Mask-RCNN-training-with-docker-containers-on-Sagemaker

Comment: The log screenshot you paste contains no error. See what's the last printouts you have for the training job (training job logs from the web console).
does it gets stuck forever? or errors out?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it gets stuck forever displaying "In Progress" status on the training job logs.

Comment: No sure what the repo you mentioned contains, it might be buggy in some way - although you're saying locally it work fine. I know about another MaskRCNN implementation with many performance enhancement, if you'd like to try that instead: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/distributed-mask-rcnn-training-with-amazon-sagemakercv/

Answer (score 0):

As Gili mentioned in the comments, you can try the example he pointed out or report the issue to the developer - https://github.com/simone-viozzi/Mask-RCNN-training-with-docker-containers-on-Sagemaker/issues.